# CSS getting block-level transparency

Tags: html, css, overlay, css-grid

I am working with grid-algorithms and found an image to produce.  For some reason the overlay properties are giving my different overlay views than the grid I want.

[image]

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 40fr 40fr 40fr 40fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-template-areas: " item1 item1 item1 item1", "item2 item2 item2 item2";
}

.item1 {
   grid-row: span 3;
   grid-column: span 3;
   grid-row-end: span;
   grid-column-end: span; 
   border: .1em solid #c09dac;
   background-color: lightgrey;
   border-color: #80949b;
   border-radius: 25px;
   text-align: center;
}

.item2 {
   grid-row: 2/4;
   grid-column: 2/4;
   grid-column-end: span 1;
   z-index:1; 
   grid-row-end: span;
   border: .1em solid #e2bec5;
   background-color:  #e4bcc4;
   border-color: #e2bec5;
   border-radius: 25px;
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item1">One</div>
  <div class="item2">Two</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answered my own question.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 40fr 40fr 40fr 40fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-template-areas: " item1 item1 item1 item1", "item2 item2 item2 item2";
}

.item1 {
   grid-row: 1 / 3;
   grid-column: 1 / 4;
   grid-row-end: span;
   grid-column-end: span;
   border: .1em solid #c09dac;
   background-color: lightgrey;
   border-color: #80949b;
   border-radius: 25px;
   text-align: center;
}

.item2 {
   grid-row: 2/4;
   grid-column: 2/5;
   grid-column-end: span ;
   z-index:1; 
   grid-row-end: span;
   border: .1em solid #e2bec5;
   background-color:  #e4bcc4;
   border-color: #e2bec5;
   border-radius: 25px;
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item1">One</div>
  <div class="item2">Two</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code like below:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
}

.grid > * {
  border-radius: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  /* take 2 rows and 3 columns and start at 1,1 by default */
  grid-row:var(--s,1) / span 2;
  grid-column:var(--s,1) / span 3;
  border: .1em solid #80949b;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.item2 {
  --s: 2; /* we change the starting to 2,2*/
  background-color: #e4bcc4;
  border-color: #e2bec5;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item1">One</div>
  <div class="item2">Two</div>
</div>
```